# jQuery издает шум?!

Tags: jquery, javascript

Всем привет!

Заметил, что **jQuery**, при работе (*выпадающее меню, слайдер и т.д.*) **издает своеобразный  шум**.

С чем это связано и почему так происходит? - вопрос из любопытства.

Google & Yandex, ответа не дали.

Comment: обратитесь к психиатру.

Comment: @eicto, юмор оценил.

Comment: Повижные части всегда надо смазывать маслом ну или вазелином... "если вы понимаете о чем я!" :))))

Comment: @Димка, с Вашим комментарием, Вам нужно на форум авто-механиков, либо на форум к Петросяну, если, Вы понимаете о чем я ...:))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Этот шум создает не JQuery. Это наводки на плохо экранированный звуковой провод от видеосигнала.
Наиболее заметен он, если колонки встроены в монитор, а звуковой кабель подключен спереди.

Еще иногда MsWord может шуметь при прокрутке текста
Расслабьтесь. Если раздражает - придется обзаводиться либо внешней звуковушкой(*), либо усилителем с принудительным подавлением шума.

P.S. eicto, зря вы так. Проблема есть, вам повезло, что у вас хорошее оборудование... Или нет звука вообще ^___^

Comment: внешняя звуковуха дешевле. еще как вариант, выключить громкость на входных каналах (line, mic)

Comment: !!!!да, конечно звуковухой =) Спс.

Answer (score 4):

> выпадающее меню, слайдер

Эффекты, которые вы упомянули, связаны с частой перерисовкой областей окна браузера (десятки раз в секунду == слышимый диапазон), и, наверное, могут сопровождаться звуковыми наводками, заметными в некоторых конфигурациях железа.

Comment: вряд-ли это было бы только с jquery связано, если фонит видюха, ну это короче нереально на современном железе услышать, хотя, я помню, у одного товарища был похожий эффект от какой-то проги (причем шум был не от колонок а как-то от корпуса),  может и правда какой-то сложнонаведенный резонанс.